# Ionic 2 adds line breaks when building release APK

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a new Ionic 2 app where I use list items.

When I build a debug version and install it the content of my list items that overflows gets simply cut at the end which is the behavior that I need:

[image]

(In the 'Destino' line the text is too long and gets cut at the end.)

Now, when I build the same app for production:

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

the text does not get cut but a line break is added. This destroys my layout and I want the text always in only one line.

How can I achieve this? Why is there a diference in building debug and release APKs?

Comment: Do you test the both versions on the same device/screen?

Comment: Yes, I installed both versions on my Galaxy S6.

Comment: just add css `white-space: nowrap` to your text